# Data backup on AWS

Tags: backup, amazon-web-services

I need to backup a few files, no more than 1Gb initially.  These files represent the mission critical data for my startup.  If I lose the AWS machines on which the live data is hosted I need to be able to restore the data to new machines with no delay, which puts me off Amazon Glacier as the blurb I have read so far is vague in terms of restoration SLA and certainly mentions hours, whereas I need minutes.  Should I be using S3? What are my options? I intend to keep daily backups going back 5 days, weekly for 2, monthly for 2 so after two months circa 9Gb total.

Comment: if you need minutes for restore, why are you backing up online at all ? Offsite physical backups rotated out would seem more logical ?

Comment: Physical? My data is on AWS VMs, seems more logical to find a cloud based solution,

Comment: sorry, totally missed that in your post !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 is an excellent option. I currently use it with several scripts to do backups for systems files, docroots and database dumps. Some pointers would be:

- use bucket expiration policies when syncing backups to your S3 bucket's different prefixes (`daily/`, `weekly/` and `monthly/`) - sync a date named directory and let S3 take care of the retention policy
- also have a prefix called `last-backup/` with no expiration policy and do not sync to a date named directory. If something is wrong for a long time and all the other backups expire, this one will not
- if you want the beginnings of a DR strategy, also sync to another bucket in another region. I use us-east-1 and us-west-2 because they have the same cost

Comment: As of may 20th, S3 now supports life cycle and versioning together, so that may be an easier solution. http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/05/20/amazon-s3-now-supports-lifecycle-rules-for-versioning/